# Evaluating Expressions with Kronecker Deltas

Tags: vectors, tensors, kronecker-delta

I am trying to learn about vector/tensor math and stumbled across these exercises in my textbook.

(1) Evaluate the expression $\delta _j^i \delta _i^j $ 
(2) Evaluate the expression $\delta _i^i \delta _j^j $ 
(3) Simplify the expression $S_i S^j \delta _j^i $

How would one go about evaluating these? Is it as simple as contracting the expressions (where (!) would cancel out completely) or is it necessary to look at the identity matrices in the cases where i=j and i=/=j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the range of the index.
Assuming it is $n$, expression (1) $=n$, while expression (2) $=n^2$.  Expression (3) $=S_iS^i$.

Comment: Is this due to the fact that Kronecker deltas are equal to 1 when i = j?

Comment: Yes - that is the definition. $\delta_i^j=1$ when $i=j$ and $=0$, when $i\ne j$.  Note that the summation convention implies that $S_iS^i$ means the sum over $i$.

Comment: I  understand that this is the definition. I guess I am failing to see how an n^2 can come out of a summation because of this though.

Comment: It is a double sum.of products of $n$ terms of $ \delta_i^i$ with $n$ terms of $ \delta_j^j$,